# Custom input number in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, foreach

I have make a new style for my input number, and this work well.
My problem is when I add this is a foreach structure this doesn't work. 
I think the problem is the ID change the value, but inside the foreach all all inputs have the same ID.

This is my code inside the foreach:

```
    <div class='value-button' id='decrease' onclick='decreaseValue()' value='Decrease Value'>-</div>
                <input size='1' id='number' name='product[<?= $p->id ?>]' value='<?= $p->qty ?>' />
<div class='value-button' id='increase' onclick='increaseValue() 'value='Increase Value'>+</div>
```

This is the js code:

```
    function increaseValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}

function decreaseValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

I have try to give unique id, but dosen't work. If I add like `<?= $p->id ?>` instead of `id number` this does not work.

How I can do?
If needed, I can also change the html of the input.

Thank you

This is My last test:

```
<td class="qty">
      <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
        <input size="1" id="92" name="product[92]" value="3">
      <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue() " value="Increase Value">+</div>
      <script>
      function increaseValue() {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('92').value);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        document.getElementById('92').value = value;
      }

      function decreaseValue() {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('92').value);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
        value--;
        document.getElementById('92').value = value;
      }
      </script>
    </td>
```

I try to add the js inside the foreach, with the same id of the input. But doesn't work.

Comment: Just a side-note, `id` should always be unique

Comment: I try to add the same api <?= $p->id ?> in the input id and js but doesn't work. And put all inside the foreach loop. but work only the least row

Comment: Can you var dump or console log the data and post it. It would help with code writing to know the structure of your data.

Comment: yes, now add the output of my last test. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the id of the input as parameter for calling `increaseValue` and `decreaseValue`. The attribute `id` should be unique and you could use a proper prefix and the product number/identifier for it.

Maybe you change the quoting for attribute to `"`, instead of `'` (this could be a matter of a given style guide). If you do so, then stay allways by the same style. You could nest quotes by using the other unused quote inside of a javascript parameter.

```
onclick="decreaseValue('product[<?= $p->id ?>]')"
        ^                                       ^  outer
                       ^                      ^    inner
```

```js
function increaseValue(id) {
    var value = +document.getElementById(id).value || 0;
    value++;
    document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}

function decreaseValue(id) {
    var value = +document.getElementById(id).value || 0;
    value--;
    if (value < 1) {
        value = '';
    }
    document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
```

```html
<div class="value-button" onclick="decreaseValue('product[<?= $p->id ?>]')">-</div>
<input size="1" id="product[<?= $p->id ?>]" name="product[<?= $p->id ?>]" value="" />
<div class="value-button" onclick="increaseValue('product[<?= $p->id ?>]')">+</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, You mean add the  <?= $p->id ?> inside the (id) ?  in the js and html?

Comment: it would be sufficient, if this part appears where actually `'number'` is in.

Comment: If I give `document.getElementById(' <?= $p->id ?>').value` (and also in the html id and onlick) work only the last row.

Comment: please watch white space in strings.

Comment: OK! sorry I was not copy well your code :) Now work!! I can ask you why what you have did? thank you!

Comment: you could use the two functions with a dynamic approach for any other inputs who have the same pattern with +/-.